# c# Selecting download link on a webpage

Tags: c#, forms, networking, browser, download

I am trying to create a c# program that will be able to automatically download lectures from Macquarie University's Echo Centre.

Example link: http://echo.mq.edu.au:8080/ess/portal/section/ANTH106_FHFYR_2012

The problem is I have no idea how to select the download link for the mp3 or m4v (if at all possible). The only solution I have come up with is downloading the source and attempting to parse it for links.

If someone could please advise me on how to select download links from within a browser object that would be excellent :) Otherwise I will just try working with the source.

```
Broswer browser = new Broswer(address);

if (!System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
{
    MessageBox.Show("This machine needs to be connected to the internet to download your lectures.\n\nPlease connect to the internet and try again.", "Network Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}

else
{
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to scrape the page's HTML and look for links. You can either try an available API for reading HTML documents programmatically, such as the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), or parsing it manually, using regex or whatever you'd like.

Once you have the URL to a file, you can use `HttpWebRequest` to programmatically download a file.

```
        var request = WebRequest.Create(" http://echo.mq.edu.au:8080/ess/portal/section/file.pdf");
        var response = request.GetResponse();

        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite("c:\lectures\file.pdf")) 
        {
                var buffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                while (bytesRead > 0) 
                {
                    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use `WebClient`.
First download the page HTML using WebClient method `DownloadString` then Parse the links for download and download the files one by one using `DowloadData`.